# Missing documentation for ServerPod 1.2.6

Tags: flutter, dart, serverpod

I just installed the Dart ServerPod 1.2.6 version but the there is no documentation available for  this verison, also there is no option available to downgrade
[image: Note on the Serverpod site]

Is there is any option available to downgrade the version? or there is any other way?